# Webworker crashes chrome tab after a while of running

Tags: reactjs, web-worker

I have a webworker in a react component that will calls an API to get data from server every 1 seconds.
It works fine at first, but after a while chrome tab will freezes and shows nothing, but worker still works in the background. what is the problem? what should I do?

**Update on this:**

the worker is really CPU consuming. High usage of CPU will cause the crash. it is just an API call, why it is so CPU consuming? and how should I fix this?

this is my code:

worker.js:

```
onmessage = (event) => {
    const { _subservice, token, backendServer } = event.data
    const getData = async () => {
        const body = {
            subservice: _subservice,
            command: 'info'
        };
        try {
            fetch(backendServer, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'data': body
                })
            }).then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    postMessage(data.response)
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    };
    const nextInterval = () => {
        getData();
        setTimeout(function () {
            nextInterval();
        }, 1000)
    }
    nextInterval()
    // setInterval(() => {
    //     getData();
    // }, 1000);
}
```

react component:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const worker = new Worker('worker.js')
    const token = localStorage.getItem(Constants.TOKEN);
    const backendServer = window['backendServer'];

    worker.postMessage({ _subservice, token, backendServer })

    worker.onmessage = (event) => {
      setData(event.data)
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
    worker.onmessageerror = (event) => {
      console.log('msg errrrrrror', event)
    }
    worker.onerror = (event) => {
      console.error('error received from worker:', event);
    }

    return () => {
      setIsLoading(false)
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? Your app might be crashing for some other reason.

Comment: @eventHandler there is no error, I think it should have happened because of memory leak or some other performance issues of worker.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to create the web worker globally on top of the file (and not in useEffect or inside the component). Most likely multiple instances are being created.

```js
const worker = new Worker('worker.js')

function MyComp(){
  useEffect(() => {
    worker.onmessage = ...
  }, [])

}
```

You can use useRef with some checks to initialize the web worker in the component. But that's not worth the pain I guess?

Comment: I have tried creating worker outside of the useEffect, but causes heavy usage of memory (14GB!), and finally crashed again.

Comment: What about doing it globally, outside of the functional component definition?

Comment: this also crashes. in this way memory usage is around 400MB, but it shows very high power usage.

Comment: I also tried creating worker using useRef, and still no difference.